# What's wrong with this ring counter made using D Flip Flop?

Tags: flipflop, counter

I have created this ring counter using D Flip Flop in multisim(I am learning counters). It's not working maybe due to the switch provided on the top left for the preset pin of D Flip Flop. I have no idea how to correct it. Any help would be highly appreciated.
[image]

Comment: Modify the way the switch of the preset works. Pullup the pin to VCC with a resistor and then use the switch to connect the pin to GND when the switch is pressed. Also make sure to add pullup connections to all of the other unused PRE and CLR pins. It is not good practice to just leave these open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, you could add a NAND3 gate from the first 3 outputs to the first D flip flop input so you'll get the first '1' in to the counter when the first 3 outputs are all zeroes. Or you could play with the resets. Or make some other combinatorial logic arrangement, depending on what your *application* for the ring counter is.